# Accessing class through $variable within another class?

Tags: php, class, global

I have a few classes, initiated on index.php, like so:

```
<?php
require_once('./classes/core.class.php');
require_once('./classes/forum.class.php');
$core = new core();
$forum = new forum();
?>
```

Is there any way to use $core within $forum? I can do it by using `core::functionName()` but not by `$core->functionName()`.

The classes are:

```
<?php
class forum{
    public function functionName(){
```

I can access it by defining the class again within each function

```
public function functionName(){
    $core = new core();
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean `$core` within `$forum`? With the code you provided, `$core->functionName()` should work just fine. Where does `$forum` come into play?

Comment: The class example I gave should be forum, rather than core. Updating it now.

Answer (score 3):

You can e.g. pass the core object to the constructor of the forum class and store it as a member.

```
$forum = new forum($core);


class forum {
  protected $core = null;
  public function __construct(core $core) {
    $this->core = $core;
  }

  public function foo() {
    $this->core->foo('forum');
  }
}
```

There are other ways to make one object accessible within another, but this is one of the simpler yet feasible solutions.
see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection

Answer (score 0):

You could inject it, look this example

```
class forum {
    public function hello() {
        return "Hello";
    }
}

class core {
    private $forum;

    public function setForum($forum) {
        $this->forum = $forum;
    }

    public function helloFromForum() {
        echo $this->forum->hello();
    }
}

$f = new forum();
$c = new core();

$c->setForum($f);
$c->helloFromForum();
```

Similar way if you like frameworks, it's Zend Registry http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.registry.html